# Wrong X509IssuerName, X509SerialNumber Error in Zatca xml Validation

Tags: xml, openssl, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

## Wrong X509IssuerName, X509SerialNumber Error (Zatca FATOORA Simulation portal)

I'm currently integrating KSA Zatca eInvoicing Phase 2 into my workflow and encountering an issue with the FATOORA Simulation portal. The process involves testing on the simulation portal before implementing it on the FATOORA production portal.

**Steps Completed:**

1. **Generated CSR using a config file** (example config file contents provided in the question).

```
oid_section = OIDs
[OIDs]
certificateTemplateName= 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2
[req]
default_bits = 2048
emailAddress = mycompany@gmail.com
req_extensions =v3_req
x509_extensions =v3_ca
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn
[dn]
C=SA
OU=3000555085
O=Testing Pvt Ltd
CN = testingstore.com
[v3_req]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment
[req_ext]
certificateTemplateName = ASN1:PRINTABLESTRING:PREZATCA-Code-Signing
subjectAltName= dirName:alt_names
[alt_names]
SN=1-TST|2-TST|3-ed24f1d8-e5a2-1118-9b58-d6a8f11e636f9
UID=300078787800003
title=1100
registeredAddress=JKKA2003
businessCategory=Food Stores
```

2. **Request a pre-compliance CSID** (https://gw-fatoora.zatca.gov.sa/e-invoicing/simulation/compliance)
3. **Run compliance checks for reporting and clearance** (https://gw-fatoora.zatca.gov.sa/e-invoicing/simulation/compliance/invoices)
4. **Request a production CSID** (https://gw-fatoora.zatca.gov.sa/e-invoicing/simulation/production/csids)
5. **Signing xml**: Signed XML by decoding the binarySecurityToken obtained from step 4 (PCSID) and using it as the certificate in the Zatca SDK.
6. **Validating Signed xml file** https://sandbox.zatca.gov.sa/TestXML

While the Standard Invoices XML successfully validates on the https://sandbox.zatca.gov.sa/TestXML site, issues arise when using *Simplified Invoice XML*. I consistently encounter issues related to incorrect X509IssuerName and X509SerialNumber[-->Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RorgF.png).

- The values obtained for IssuerName and SerialNumber are(its got from simulation PCSID Certificate):

```html
<ds:X509IssuerName>CN=PEZEINVOICESCA2-CA, DC=extgazt, DC=gov, DC=local</ds:X509IssuerName>
<ds:X509SerialNumber>413713212005634976763820571758723157758585483</ds:X509SerialNumber>
```

I'm uncertain if this error is due to using FATOORA simulation APIs. Will transitioning to FATOORA core APIs resolve this issue? Any guidance on resolving this X509IssuerName and X509SerialNumber error would be greatly appreciated.

*Is there a problem with the issuer name and serial number? Could this issue be a result of using FATOORA simulation APIs? If I switch to FATOORA core APIs, will it resolve itself? I'm seeking a solution for this concern.*

Comment: The certificate is failing to validate against an actual issuer.  You have to pay to issuer to use the certificate.  When you simulate the certificate is properly validating which indicates your code is working properly.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your insightful response. I appreciate your clarification on the certificate validation issue. Could you kindly guide me on the payment process to the issuer, specifically Zakat, Tax, and Customs Authority? Unfortunately, the official documentation doesn't provide details on the certificate payment procedure. If you have any relevant documentation or insights on this matter, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share them. Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: See https://wpmudev.com/blog/ssl-certificate-authorities-reviewed/

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for sharing the link. I'll make sure to review the information there. I appreciate your continued assistance. Thank you!

Comment: @Byte_Box Did you find the solution to this error? I, too, have the same error in the simulation portal.